# Why this syntax useEffect(callback[, dependencies]); is used to show that useEffect has two argument?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, syntax

This is what is used:

`useEffect(callback[, dependencies]);`

Why does the **square brakets begin with a coma**?
I my mind , I have something like this:

`useEffect(callback, [dependencies]);`

Thanks for your explanations.

Comment: Where are you seeing the first example used or recommended? It's syntactically incorrect. The second is correct

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava  Yes. It's clear now. Thanks.

Comment: @BrianThompson it's a common syntax for documentation used on many sites like mdn. The second syntax would suggest that adding a trailing comma is ok.

Comment: I didn't see any indication that it was talking about documentation, but that would make sense.